# Python re.search Regex matching

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that will match a string based on the the following criteria:

```
• must start with ABC, DEF, or GHI
• above must be followed by exactly 1 space character 
• above must be followed by a number>=0 such that if it is an integer with 4+ digits 
  then it must be separated by comma (for example) 9,876 or if a decimal, 
  then must have exactly 2 decimal places (for example) 0.99 or 9.80;
  no leading zeroes like 010 or 010.10 are allowed.
```

I tried this, but not matching what is required:

```
((ABC)|(DEF)|(GHI))\w[0-9]+
```

In the above, \w is for whitespace and [0-9]+ means 1 or more integers. I’m not sure how to represent decimals constrained by above requirements.

For example,

ABC 0.99 should match
ABC 1,999,889 should match
DEF 10.00 should match
DEF 10 should match
ABC       0.99 should not match
CYZ 1 should not match
GHI 0123 should not match

Comment: _"exactly 1 space character"_, wouldn't you use `[ ]` instead of `\w`? Also, isn't `\s` _any_ white-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This translates to

```
^
(?:ABC|DEF|GHI)
\ 
(?:
    (?:[1-9],\d{3})(?:,\d{3})*
    |
    [1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{2})?
)
$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rfc1ax/6/).

Comment: It is failing DEF 10.00 and DEF 10 cases (should be matched but got no match)

Comment: it is failing above 2 cases as mentioned

Comment: @user: I will look into it. But please add samples that should be matched and thos which don't in the question.

Comment: it is now matching ABC 011.11 when it should not match it

Comment: it is allowing leading zeroes now

Comment: @user: Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following expression:

```
^              LINE START
(ABC|DEF|GHI)  LITERAL CHAR SEQUENCES: [ ABC, DEF, GHI ]
\s             WHITE-SPACE
(?!            BEGIN NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD
  0            LITERAL CHAR: '0'
)              END NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD
\d{1,3}        NUMERIC CHAR: 1-3
(              BEGIN GROUP
  ,            LITERAL CHAR: ','
  \d{3}        NUMERIC CHAR: 3
)              END GROUP
*              ZERO OR MORE
(              BEGIN GROUP
  \.           LITERAL CHAR: '.'
  \d{2}        NUMERIC CHAR: 2
)              END GROUP
?              OPTIONAL GROUP
$              LINE END
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(ABC|DEF|GHI)\s(?!0)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$')

valid = [
  'ABC 1',
  'DEF 1.11',
  'GHI 1,111'
]

invalid = [
  'ABC 01',
  'DEF 1.1',
  'GHI 1111',
  'JKL 1.11'
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('All valid: {}'.format(all(pattern.match(str) for str in valid)))
  print('All invalid: {}'.format(all(not pattern.match(str) for str in invalid)))
```

### Browser test

```js
const pattern = /^(ABC|DEF|GHI)\s(?!0)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$/;

const allValid = [
  'ABC 1',
  'DEF 1.11',
  'GHI 1,111'
].every(str => str.match(pattern));

const allInvalid = [
  'ABC 01',
  'DEF 1.1',
  'GHI 1111',
  'JKL 1.11'
].every(str => !str.match(pattern));

console.log({ allValid, allInvalid });
```